# Can you name this systems of subsets?

Tags: general-topology

Recently I was working on systems of subsets satisfying the following properties

[image]

Obviously, it is just useful partitioning for further magic but I wonder if there is some theoretical treatment of such systems. Any suggestion for reading is welcome

Comment: $4$ is not really a property, rather a definition of more variables...

Comment: It would improve your Question to highlight early on that $S$ is a topological space.

Comment: What is $\Sigma$ supposed to be? .

Comment: There is a relation between this and a thing called a Partition Of Unity.

Comment: $\Sigma$ should be switchning manifold. In fact, this partition comes from piece-wise smooth ODEs